# No DB associated to model problem FastApi and Tortoise ORM & aerich

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I've got a project made by FastApi with Tortoise ORM and aerich migrations.
Aerich initialization was completed successfully, all migrations were done too. Here u can see my main.py:

```
app = FastAPI()

Tortoise.init_models(settings.TORTOISE_MODELS_LIST, "models")
register_tortoise(
    app, config=settings.TORTOISE_ORM,
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)

app.include_router(purchases.router.router)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", debug=True, reload=True, lifespan='on')
```

Here is settings.py where TORTOISE_MODELS_LIST is placed:

```
TORTOISE_MODELS_LIST = ["purchases.models", "aerich.models"]

TORTOISE_ORM = {
    "connections": {"default": DATABASE_URL},
    "apps": {
        "models": {
            "models": TORTOISE_MODELS_LIST,
            "default_connection": "default",
        },
    },
}
```

I've not problems on startup, but when I run this method:

```
@router.get("/get/latest", tags=["purchases"], response_model=List[Purchase_Pydantic],
            description="Shows last 25 purchases")
async def get_latest_purchases():
    purchases = await Purchase.all()[:25]
    return Purchase_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(purchases)
```

I have such strange problem:

```
tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: No DB associated to model
```

How to solve this issue? Aerich seems to be working cool...

Comment: Hey @ftelnov. Could i ask you some Questions about how you implemented aerich with TortoiseOrm? I am struggling to find any documentation on how the migrations will work. Is it automatically created from your models? and does it work with PostgreSQL? if you have any other info that would be great

Comment: @bruzza42 Aerich have a good documentation. You just need to call init-db for generating schema and first migration. From this time whenever you call migrate, it generates new .sql migration file. To apply changes you just need to call upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunatetly documentation problems seem to be a fact of life with TortoiseOrm. Its missing a *LOT* of critical details (Heres a fun one for you. What options can go in meta? Who knows, its not documented.

Comment: Also, strong recomendation not to rely on autogenerated migrations with aerich. They can and will generate out of dependency order requiring you to go in and manually reorder them. Might be just easier to just manually write them. Its a fairly half-baked library to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone see such bug: in models list place not a relative module name, but an absolute. So it will be 'app.items.models', and not 'items.models'. Works for me.